# Sitefinity 12.1 is crashing Azure Webapp

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, sitefinity

Sitefinity is crashing himself which is hosted in azure .Net webapp while uploading the documents into azure blob storage

We do have multiple Sitefinity sites and only one site is crashing himself while document publishing in to azure blob storage.
Created a separate Resource group and hosted the web app and separate SQL DB and storage account also.
Exactly crashing while uploading the documents but it's working fine while with local file storage.
Checked all the logs and found no issues... any clue ...

Comment: Does the site crash if you run it locally, while still using the same Azure Blob Storage provider?

Comment: No it's not crashing when i am running locally... it's working like a normal but if i am changing to blob and upload some files it's crashing...

Comment: So it crashes locally if you use the Azure Blob provider? What Sitefinity version is this?

Comment: I am using 12.1... On locally with azure blob i have not tried... i will try and let you know in this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me it's trying to upload files locally (inside the web app), but using a wrong path rather than uploading to azure storage. One thing you can do: enable log streamming then you'll know for sure what happenned.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs

Comment: Hi,The files are uploaded sucessfully to blobstorage, once it's uploaded to storage sitefinity is automatically crashing..

Comment: enable the log, you'll definitely get some errors there.

Comment: You are suspecting some issues on the storage side... I enabled the same to debug those issues but getting success code only...

Comment: that was my first assumption, but as you said it's saving the blob correctly, it should be something else. Enable the stream log and check for any error messages.

Comment: Hi Thiago, I am getting 404 errors for 2 files (icon and Font ) which we are missing in the server. Other then that i could not able to get any error. Running out of idea where i am missing... whether the error is related to Blob or Sitefinity or SQL DB... :-(

Answer (score 0):

If the azure blob storage is failing on local does your IP have access to the resource in azure? If not this could cause a failed.